# How to extract month name of date from MySql query

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this query which checks for a data repeating four times on the same month 4 or more times. I need to extract the month name or number from this and pass it to `string` or `int`.

```
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
string query = "SELECT agentlogin, COUNT(agentlogin), LAST_DAY(`date`) AS Month FROM pending WHERE agentlogin = @login GROUP BY LAST_DAY(`date`) HAVING COUNT(agentlogin) >= 4";
MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(query, connect);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", Label1.Text);
connect.Open();
MySqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    lblmsg.Text = "GrpM Alert!";
    string getMonth = ?;
}
```

So how can I get this done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the `Month` field and [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-mmm-custom-format-specifier) it to its name

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    DateTime date = rdr.GetDateTime("Month"); 
    string getMonth = date.ToString("MMM");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be:

```
string getMonth = rdr["Month"].ToString();
```

And replace `LAST_DAY(date)` with `MONTH(LAST_DAY(date))` or some variation like `MONTH(date)`.

At every step of reading the query with `rdr.Read()` you can access current row fields through `MySqlDataReader` object
using it just like array/dictionary: `rdr[int i]`, where `i` would be index of a field in a row or `rdr[string fieldName]`,
where `fieldName` is name of a column, which you want to get from particular row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be grouping by the month, year, *and* agent login, then selecting only the year and month.  We can use `DATE_FORMAT` in this case:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') AS yearmonth
FROM pending
WHERE
    agentlogin = @login
GROUP BY
    agentlogin,     -- optional, but included for correctness
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 4;
```

Note that this may return more than one month value, if a login happens to match more than one month.

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    lblmsg.Text = "GrpM Alert!";
    int monthNumber = rdr.GetString("yearmonth");
}
```

The reason for wanting to group by the year *and* month is that different years could have the same month, and in this case, you probably don't want to report them as being the same thing.